# How to get actual folder path of directory junction?

Tags: windows-7

Few days ago I'll created [directory junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) using `mklink` command in windows 7.Now I want to know what is the actual link according to that directory junction.How I can achieve  it **without** [third party tools](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ntfs_links_view.html)?

Comment: So you are looing for a command line tool of windows instead of a GUI? Can you fix the link?

Comment: Yes you are right,but i want to know where it's can be view via windows command prompt(cmd.exe)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Navigate to the folder containing your junction in cmd.exe and run:

```
dir /a:d
```

It should list all the directories in the folder including the junction, and should give the junction's real location.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you could do this with the links you provide:

```
NTFSLinksView.exe /folder <foldername> /scomma links.csv
```

and you can view it with

```
type links.csv
```

The whole line would look like this:

```
NTFSLinksView.exe /folder <foldername> /scomma links.csv && type links.csv
```

Comment: I want to do it in inbuilt tool via windows operating system without using the third-party tools.